# Outputting the table to textbox

Tags: c#, mysql

I am faced with the problem that I can not display the table from mysql in the textbox c # I tried this code like this. Help please. Thanks

```
string cons = "Server=server;DataBase=base;Uid=u0827;pwd=kkda";
            MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection(cons);
            mycon.Open();
           
            string con = "SELECT usd FROM curs";
            MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(con);
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(com);
           MySqlDataReader DR = com.ExecuteReader();
            com.CommandText = @"select  TOP 1 usd from curs";
            
            object res = com.ExecuteScalar();
            if (res != null) usd.Text = res.ToString();
            DR.Close();
            mycon.Close();
```

When running this code, it gives an error -
System.InvalidOperationException: "Connection must be valid and open."

Comment: `Server=server;DataBase=base`; serious?

Comment: This is the modified path the connection to the MySQL database is made

Comment: I used to use a connection for authorization and everything works

Comment: You define the connection variable as `mycon`, but you pass `con` as parameter to the mysqlcommand constructor, so this is just a typo. Also, `top 1` is ms sql server syntax, mysql uses `limit 1` at the end of a select.

Comment: The error is displayed on the line
MySqlDataReader DR = com.ExecuteReader();

Comment: I tried a lot of things, nothing helps, please help

Answer (score 0):

```
 string cons = "Server=ser;DataBase=base;Uid=u082na;pwd=kkdNwijs";
            MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection(cons);


            mycon.Open();

            string con = "select * from curs";
            MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(con, mycon);

            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            myReader = com.ExecuteReader();


            try
            {
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    usd.Text = (myReader.GetString(0));
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                myReader.Close();
                mycon.Close();
            }
```